# Post Facebook photo comment via API

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

Facebook has launched its photo-comments for months, and I couldn't find any related docs on Facebook developer site.

Has anyone knows if it is possible to use its APIs to post photo-comments on friend's feed? I am currently writing this on iOS and Android as well. Being searching over the internet for a solution, but there's nothing available share tutorial. (There's a programmer said, it can use URL to post on comments, then let Facebook to detect and display as an image. But it'd be great if I can upload an image to Facebook comment via app)